KDE apps can't start and leak memory
Problem
Since I upgraded to Debian 13, KDE apps won't start and leak memory.
I use these apps (Dolphin, Spectacle, etc.) without the Plasma desktop.
I3 is the windows manager.
I am using proprietary Nvidia drivers.
I tried reinstalling the whole KDE suite, with and without the Plasma desktop (even if I don't use it), nothing changes.
Dolphin :

I start dolphin
It issues what seems to be a harmless warning :

kf.service.sycoca: The menu spec file ( "" ) contains a Layout or DefaultLayout tag without the mandatory Merge tag inside. Please fix it.


No window appears
Process dolphin is now alive and starts eating memory
It eventually gets killed after 5 minutes or so by early-oom, when the systems runs low on memory.

If interrupted by Control-C, process and leak stop and memory is freed.
Spectacle has the same behavior.
Gwenview

I start gwenview
It issues the previous warning along with others
A Gwenview window appears
It freezes immediately (I can't click, thumbnails don't load)
It starts leaking memory

Gwenview, second test

I start gwenview
It issues the previous warning along with others
A Dolphin (!) window appears
It freezes and leaks memory

Krusader
Krusader works fine.
Edit: did a package upgrade today, Krusader now has same behavior as Dolphin.
Breeze icons
Icons are still used successfully by various programs. However, they appear huge, as if they couldn't be resized.
System calls
strace dolphin reports the process infinitely calling brk()
Reset of configuration files
On my system, every /home/user/.something is a symlink to /dotfiles/user/.something on a faster drive.
So to test launching the software without .cache and .config I just removed temporarily the symlinks. Everything is indeed reset but dolphin and others still don't start and leak memory.
Package management issues
apt seems unhappy with my system, sometimes a standard upgrade is removing software I installed : for instance qgis, showfoto or even virtualbox-7.0. So after the upgrade I ask to reinstall those packages. It works after having installed/removed some libraries.

Try strace dolphin 2>some.log and then check some.log to see where it gets stuck.

It seems to load properly, then keeps calling brk() infinitely, which as I understand causes the memory leak.


logout 2. mv ~/.config ~/.config.bak mv ~/.cache ~/.cache.bak 3) log back in 4) check the results

Unfortunately KDE config/temp files are impossible to clean up otherwise: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=422529

Please add the new information to your question. Same with the results of what Artem asked above.

Ok, finally I got a fix.
The nasty file is ~/.local/share/mime/mime.cache, removing it makes everything normal again.
